# Used manage.py dbshell -> DROP TABLE to delete a database table, now I cannot recreate it

Tags: django

I am trying to use a custom Django management command to populate a db with scraped data. I messed this up on the first go so I deleted the table using `python manage.py dbshell` and then `DROP TABLE player_player` (`Player` is the name of the model). The table is now gone but when I re-run `python manage.py makemigrations` and `python manage.py migrate` it does not seem to recreate it. I tried deleting the migrations in the `player` application and ran `python manage.py makemigrations` again and it returned

```
 Migrations for 'player':
  player/migrations/0001_initial.py
    - Create model Player
```

but when I run `python manage.py migrate` it says

```
Running migrations:
 No migrations to apply
```

and does not recreate the `Player` db table.

Can anyone help with this? I was getting an error I couldn't solve so I figured I'd delete the table and try again since there was no data I cared about in there, but now think that was a poor decision.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because Django has a table named `django_migrations` that lists all the migrations that have been applied. Although you removed the *table*, Django still thinks it has applied the migration, because the name of the migration is listed in the table.

You can run the query:

```
DELETE FROM django_migrations WHERE name='0001_initial' AND app='player'
```

and then reapply the migration.

That being said, I would advise not to manually change the structure of the database. It might eventually result in putting the database in a state where fixing the database can be inconvenient.

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply. Problem solved, won't do that again.